# MySQL Matching date-based First Instance of value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing stock market data (open, hi, lo, close prices) but in a random order of date:

```
Date    Open    Hi  Lo  Close
12/10/2019  313.82  314.54  312.81  313.58
11/22/2019  311.09  311.24  309.85  310.96
11/25/2019  311.98  313.37  311.98  313.37
11/26/2019  313.41  314.28  313.06  314.08
11/27/2019  314.61  315.48  314.37  315.48
11/29/2019  314.86  315.13  314.06  314.31
12/2/2019   314.59  314.66  311.17  311.64
12/3/2019   308.65  309.64  307.13  309.55
```

I have another value in a PHP variable (say $BaseValue),and a start date and end date ($startdt and $enddt).

1) My requirement is to pick-up the value from the HI column, if it exceeds the $BaseValue on the very FIRST date in a chronological order between the given start and end dates.

For example, if the $BaseValue=314, startdt=11/22, enddt=12/2, then I want to retrieve the Date (11/26/19) as it is the earliest date on which the Hi value (314.28) exceeded the $Basevalue within the given date range. The select statement should return both the Hi value (314.28) and the Date (11/26/19).

2) Additionally, I also need to retrieve the HIGHEST value and date from the HI column during the given date duration. In the above scenario, it should return 315.48 and corresponding date 11/27.

The table is NOT in a chronological order - its randomly filled.

I am unable to get the first query at all with the use of MAX function and its various combinations. Makes me wonder if that is possible at all in SQL or not.

While the second is straightforward, I was wondering if it is more efficient and less complex to club the two queries and get the four values in one single shot.

Any ideas on how can I approach the need to fulfill this requirement please?

Thanks

Comment: Store dates using a date data type

Comment: @Strawberry, it is indeed in "date" data type (2019-11-29 format)...In the above question, I pulled the data in excel and copy-pasted from excel.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two subqueries for filtering, one per criteria, like:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    t.date = (
        select min(t1.date)
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.date between :datedt and :enddt and t1.hi >= :basevalue
    )
    or t.hi = (
        select max(t1.hi)
        from mytable t1
        where t1.date between datedt and :enddt and t1.hi >= :basevalue
    )
```

Another option is to `union` two queries with `orer by` and `limit`:

```
(
    select t.* 
    from mytable
    where t.date between :datedt and :enddt and t1.hi >= :basevalue
    order by t.date
    limit 1
)
union
    (
    select t.* 
    from mytable t
    where t.date between :datedt and :enddt and t1.hi >= :basevalue
    order by t.hi desc, t.date
    limit 1
)
```

Please note that both queries do not do *exactly* the same thing. If there are ties for the highest `hi` in the period, the first query will return all ties, while the second will pick the earliest one. It's up to you to decide which solution better fits your use case.